# In a loop what's the best practice to get input (cli) with validation, that also resumes like this?

Tags: java, loops, input, conceptual

I have written a java program to get a series of inputs from the user, step by step with the feature to move to the next question only after getting the valid input from the user like this, for example,

```
       while(true){
            while(true){                
                System.out.println("Enter ID (3 digits)");
                int id = sc.nextInt();
                if(validateID(id))
                    break
            }
            while(true){                
                System.out.println("Enter Favourite Number (2 digits)");
                int fav = sc.nextInt();
                if(validateFavNo(fav))
                    break
            }
            System.out.println("ID = "+id+" Favouroite No = "+fav);
        }
```

This is obviously not the best approach to do this
Hence, I came up with a solution, which I am not sure, whether or not it is the best approach, whic is given below, where inputProgress is a static variable which is initialized to 0 at starting.

```
while (true) {

    if (inputProgress == 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Product ID");
        pID = sc.nextInt();
        if (vController.validatePIDFormat(pID))
            inputProgress += 1;
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            continue;
    }

    if (inputProgress == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Product Name");
        pName = sc.next();
        if (vController.validatePNameFormat(pName))
            inputProgress += 1;
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        continue;
    }

    if (inputProgress == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Product Type");
        String pType = sc.next();
        pTypeID = -1;
        if (pType.contains("commodity")) {
            pTypeID = 1;
        } else if (pType.contains("equity")) {
            pTypeID = 2;
        } else if (pType.contains("derivative")) {
            pTypeID = 3;
        }
        if (pTypeID > 0 && pTypeID < 4) {
            inputProgress += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (inputProgress == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Quantity");
        pQuantity = sc.nextInt();
        if (vController.validatePQuantity(pQuantity)) {
            inputProgress += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            continue;
        }
    }

    Product newProduct = new Product(pID, pName, pQuantity, pTypeID);
    inputProgress = 0;
    return newProduct;
 }
```

My question is, whether this is a good one or is there a better approach/practice to achieve the same results as desired.

Comment: is second code block incomplete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like `while(true)`, there is always a better (and more elegant) solution.
In your case there is a lot of "inelegance", one for all `return` statement inner the loop, and `continue` to jump at the top ... no, I don't like it.

To maintain your structure, we should make it more "elengant", like this:

```
public Product readProduct() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    MockValidator vController = new MockValidator(); // mock
    // fields outside loop
    int pID = -1;
    String pName = null;
    int pTypeID = -1;
    int pQuantity = -1;

    int inputProgress = 0;
    while (inputProgress < 4) { // Loop exit condition linked to inputProgress. Exit when read all 4 valid inputs
        if (inputProgress == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Product ID");
            pID = sc.nextInt();
            if (vController.validatePIDFormat(pID)) {
                inputProgress += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }

        if (inputProgress == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Product Name");
            pName = sc.next();
            if (vController.validatePNameFormat(pName)) {
                inputProgress += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }

        if (inputProgress == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Product Type");
            String pType = sc.next();
            pTypeID = -1;
            if (pType.contains("commodity")) {
                pTypeID = 1;
            } else if (pType.contains("equity")) {
                pTypeID = 2;
            } else if (pType.contains("derivative")) {
                pTypeID = 3;
            }
            if (pTypeID > 0) {
                inputProgress += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }


        if (inputProgress == 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Quantity");
            pQuantity = sc.nextInt();
            if (vController.validatePQuantity(pQuantity)) {
                inputProgress += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }

    return new Product(pID, pName, pQuantity, pTypeID);
}
```

but, wanna be more "elegant", there are many concept repeated in your code, so we can extract some common behavior. Practically, for each parameter, you want to :

1. Read each parameter of a certain type ( `Supplier` )
2. (sometimes) Convert it in another type ( `Function` )
3. Validate it ( `Predicate` )
4. Repeat until result is valid

You can write a generic method to do that and use it for every parameter you want !

That's what I'm talking about

```
private Product readProductSmart() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    MockValidator vController = new MockValidator(); // mock

    Map<String, Integer> productTypeMap = Map.of(
            "commodity", 1,
            "equity", 2,
            "derivative", 3
    );

    int id = readUntilIsValid("Product ID", sc::nextInt, Function.identity(), vController::validatePIDFormat);
    String name = readUntilIsValid("Product Name", sc::next, Function.identity(), vController::validatePNameFormat);
    int typeId = readUntilIsValid("Product Type", sc::next, productTypeMap::get, Objects::nonNull);
    int quantity = readUntilIsValid("Quantity", sc::nextInt, Function.identity(), vController::validatePQuantity);

    return new Product(id, name, quantity, typeId);
}

private <S, T> T readUntilIsValid(String name, Supplier<S> supplier, Function<S, T> mapper, Predicate<T> validator) {
    T result = null;
    boolean valid = false;
    while (!valid) { // Repeat until result is valid
        System.out.println("Enter the " + name);
        S read = supplier.get(); // Read each parameter of a certain type
        result = mapper.apply(read); // Convert it in another type (sometimes)
        if (!(valid = validator.test(result))) { // Validate it
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

that's solution is pretty "elegant" and flexible (good for maintenance): you can easily add, remove and switch parameter(s).

Comment: Thank you Stefano Riffaldi, I've recently started to learn java, Your way of approach to the problem is super good...Thank You Again for the Knowledge!

Comment: I know that's my approach is a bit complicated to understand, I used some "pro" tools like Generics and Lambda expression, but core concepts are the same: try to avoid `while(true)` and aggregate common behavior using methods. Doing that, you code will be more "elegant" (that means readable, understandable, maintainable)